# Need clarification regarding **free variables** and **ground sentences**

Tags: predicate-logic

I have been reading *Logical Fundations of Artificial Intelligence* by Michael R. Genesereth, and have questions regarding some of his paragraphs on Page 20.

1.

> A variable can also occur as a term in a sentence without an enclosing quantifier. When used in this way, a variable is said to be *free*, whereas a variable that occurs in a sentence and in an enclosing quantifier is said to be *bound*. ....

Does the definition of **free variables** mean the sentence is without an enclosing quantifier or the variable appearing in the sentence is without one?

2.

> If a sentence has no free variables, it is called a *closed* sentence. If it has neither free nor bound variables, it is called a *ground* sentence.

Does being a ground sentence mean that the sentence has no variable at all? If no so, which kinds of variables could it contain? Are there some examples?

Comment: DO NOT SHOUT. It's rude.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I'm sorry, but I don't understand, how could one "shout" on the web?

Comment: ALL CAPS conventionally indicates yelling. To show emphasis, surround your text in *one asterisk*, **two asterisks**, or ***three asterisks*** on either side

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thank you! I didn't know lol

Comment: It doesn't work in the headline. But I think it's okay this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It means that the variable is without an enclosing quantifier.  Thus, in $\forall x (x < y)$, the variable $x$ is bound, while $y$ is free.
2. Yes, it means it has no variables at all. A language may still have *constants* to form sentences. For example, if a language has the constant $0$ and the function $+$, you could form the sentence $0+0=0$.